# How to display only the countries you ship to on checkout in magento?

Tags: magento, country

We only ship to 28 EU countries + EEA, and wonder if there is a way to reduce the list on checkout where customers currently select from the list of whole world.

Selecting "Ship to specific countries" in Configuration menu doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: programming or system-config related,  but the below answer is what we were looking for.  thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the allowed countries in the System -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Countries Option:

[image]

This will limit the number of countries in the Country drop down on all address forms, including the Billing and Shipping Address forms on the One Page Checkout.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't quite cut it when you ship to only specific countries, but accept payments from anywhere (which is not an uncommon practice). You can limit the countries per shipping method, but this still *displays* all countries from the general settings (which, to me, make little to no sense).